# Extracting Raw Data from Integer and Long Variables in Java

Tags: java, random, integer, long-integer, raw-data

I'm working on a Java project where I have been tasked with extracting raw data from both integer and long variables.

Here's an input:

```
Integer intValue = 42;
Long longValue = 9876543210L;
```

How can I extract the raw data as bytes from intValue and longValue?

Comment: maybe it would be wise to ask the "GLI (Gaming Laboratories International) team" or whoever tasked you with extracting raw data

Comment: @user16320675 we are trying to findout the things from our end, so asked the question here

Comment: no sure what is meant by 'our end'... who better would know 'the exact meaning or requirements of "raw data" ' (my understanding is that an integer {or long} already is raw data... unless they are composed, like bit-masks or so) || anyway the question is unclear (maybe clear for someone involved with that GLI)

Comment: @user16320675 please check the answer, this is what i need i believe, but will clarify the answer with GLI team

Comment: Beats me why hex representation is raw data.  Its more encoded than the variables.  Nutty requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For integer

```
byte[] bytes = ByteBuffer.allocate(Integer.BYTES).putInt(42).array();

for (byte b : bytes) {
   System.out.format("0x%x ", b);
}
```

For long

```
byte[] bytes = ByteBuffer.allocate(Long.BYTES).putLong(9876543210L).array();

for (byte b : bytes) {
   System.out.format("0x%x ", b);
}
```

The above prints in hexadecimal format. To print each byte as 0/1 style bits use:

```
   System.out.format(String.format("%8s", Integer.toBinaryString(b & 0xFF)).replace(' ', '0'));
```

Comment: `Integer.BYTES` and `Long.BYTES` provide the size of each type in bytes.  And you have one too many opening parens after allocate.

Comment: @WJS  Fixed the double parenthesis typo. But SIZE - The number of **bits** used to represent a long value in two's complement binary form.

Comment: @JohnWilliams I see you are printing 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 in format of: 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x1 Can you please elaborate why it is being done in that format?

Comment: 0x indicates hexidecimal. What format do you prefer? binary? 01011010

Comment: *`But SIZE - The number of bits used to represent a long value in two's complement binary form.`*  I know, and  BYTES is  but since you are computing the number of bytes in a long or int to allocate the byte array I just thought the existing predefined values would be clearer.  Both work equally well.

Comment: @JohnWilliams can you please also tell how to represent it in binary?

Comment: @AakashPatel I have added to binary System.out.format to the answer.

Comment: To print the original value in binary with padding you can do `String bits = Integer.toBinaryString(intValue);System.out.println("0".repeat(Integer.SIZE-bits.length()) + bits);`

Comment: Thank you @JohnWilliams this has been what i was looking for. My code for generating random numbers as per GLI standard is approved.

Comment: Thank you @WJS for providing valueable imrovements